# Find a specific word and replace that before the "letter" rather than after

Tags: java, eclipse, replace, cpu-word

I have an alphabet which I want to replace before any alphabet rather than the after. For example if I have a word "instant" I want to make sure that char 'a' after the 't' should be before the 't'. It should be insatnt. Wherever any of the word has an 'a' it should be replaced before but not after. Is there any possible way out of this?

Comment: So the output of `instant` should be `insatnt`?

Comment: Is this in code or a search and replace in the IDE?

Comment: @jlordo: Yes, I am using a different language that's how I want it to be.

Comment: @BoristheSpider: I am not really sure what you mean?

Comment: Are you writing a program in Eclipse that need to do this or are you trying to use Eclipse to search and replace in your existing code base? I'm confused by the eclipse tag.

Comment: @BoristheSpider: I am sorry but I want to write a program in Eclipse not searching and replacing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have only given one example, so I can't post a general answer. Maybe you can generalize  it:

```
String input = "instant";
String replaced = input.replaceAll("(\\w)a", "a$1");
```

Comment: This is awesome. Will it be possible to do that in HTML file as well? Or Can I pull the string from the html file and place them? I have over 1000 html files which I want to replace the texts.

Comment: @ivesingh: It will work with anything you have in `String` format. Beware, that this would also change the html `<head>` tag to `<haed>` which you probably don't want happening.

Answer (score 1):

You can use regex to do what you want.

In the general case you want to replace `<something>a` by `a<something>` where `<something>` is a single character, any character.

In regex this is replacing `(\\w)a` by `a$1`, i.e. find cases where an `a` is preceded by something and capture that something. Then replace it with the `a` followed by the captured something:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    final String s = "instant";
    System.out.println(s.replaceAll("(\\w)a", "a$1"));
}
```

Output:

```
insatnt
```

Answer (score 0):

The old-school way would be something along the following:

```
char reference_char = 'a';
String old_string = "instant";

char[] test_array = old_string.toCharArray();        
int i = 0;

for (char c : test_array) {
    if (i > 0) {
        if (c == reference_char) {
            test_array[i] = test_array[i - 1];
            test_array[i - 1] = reference_char;
        }
    }
    ++i;
}

String new_string =  new String(test_array);
System.out.println(new_string);
```

I hope I understood your question.

All the best!